# ¿Cómo crear una función que verifique el logueo del usuario PHP?

Tags: php

He creado la siguiente `function`:

```
function is_logged() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['correcto'])) return $_SESSION['correcto'] === TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Tras haberla creado al ingresado los datos del usuario de manera correcta:

```
$_SESSION['correcto'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['id_user'] = $id_user;
```

La idea de crear una `function` es para poder hacer uso de esa comprobación de una manera más sencilla en ciertas areas/partes de una página que se requiera ocultar o mostrar cosas o simplemente direccionar al login si no esta logueado:

```
if (is_logged() === FALSE) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Funciona, pero la pregunta en sí, si es seguro emplearlo de esa manera o que otros parámetros se le deben agregar para reforzar la seguridad.

Comment: Esta correcto el metodo para verificar el loggeo, si quieres agregar seguridad, haz que la sesion expire en determinado tiempo (1 hora)

Comment: Yo me cuelgo para colgar una duda... Es necesario crear una función ?? No es mejor simplemente hacer la comprobación al inicio de la página, y si no existe sesión, te redireccione directamente a otro lado, de este modo no llegarían nunca a la función no ?¿?

Comment: @Excorpion Para temas precisos como por ejemplo, en carro de compra oculto las áreas o las funciones de `pagar ahora` sino esta iniciado sesión otras cosas por ejemplo en el menú de navegación oculto las etiquetas `li` que tiene enlaces de `Registrarte Ahora | Iniciar Sesión` en vez de eso muestro un `menú toggle` sobre sus datos de `perfil, configuración de la cuenta, cerrar sesión` entre otros. Para eso lo utilizo, no es una manera más simple de hacerlo? en vez de realizar esto `if (isset($_SESSION['correcto']) && $_SESSION['correcto'] === TRUE) {} else {}` }

Comment: Si, algo como esto, si la sesión existe, pasas, sino, sácame de inmediato y mandame a login. Esa parte, es necesaria ingresarla en una funcion ? o no hay diferencia en que sea sin funcion ?

Comment: Eso no es lo mismo que: `if(isset($_SESSION) === false){header("location: login.php"}; exit;` ??

Comment: @Excorpion Es que no te entendí, eso si es lo mismo, pero no agregas valor a `$_SESSION` `PHP` puede generar `$_SESSION` cuando se añaden por ejemplo artículos al carro de compra. Pero en sí, esto `is_logged()` es para la que ya comente, no precisamente es para hacer esto `header("location: login.php");`